# Make image of, and restore iPad Mini flash chip?

Tags: ipad, backup, jailbreak, disk-image

Is it possible to make an image of the entire disk of an iPad Mini 1 that’s running iOS 6.1.3 using dd over ssh, for the purpose of backing up and restoration? Additional info below…

iPad Mini 2,5 jailbroken no passcode

Device does not contain the Secure Enclave coprocessor

iOS versions prior to 8 could have a tweak installed that allowed for the device to be mounted as a usb drive.

Comment: To what end? I’m struggling to see the point.

Comment: Archival purposes. If something goes wrong I’d like to be able to just restore everything back to the way it was when it was working. I intend this to be a kind of legacy device, a sort of time capsule. If this is the kind of thing that requires opening the device and micro-soldering, then forget it.